# Error opencv 470 no abre camara onvif red local java

Tags: java, opencv, stream

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que me abra la cámara en red loca, tengo una cámara que soporta onvif y puedo verla por vlc con la siguiente url:

***rtsp://ip:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif***

Al abrir esa url en vlc me abre una pequeña ventana en la cual ingreso user y pass y se ve correctamente la cámara.
Pero en el programa que estoy escribiendo utilizo la url

***rtsp://admin:pass@ip:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0***

o la

***rtsp://admin:pass@ip:554/Streaming/Channels/101***

y no lo reproduce la ventana, da el error:

**Failed to open the camera.**

***luego al cerrar la ventana veo por log lo siguiente:***

[ INFO:0@0.008] global videoio_registry.cpp:232 cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(9, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930); OBSENSOR(920)

[ INFO:0@0.009] global backend_plugin.cpp:383 cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 3 plugin(s) for FFMPEG

[ INFO:0@0.009] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg470_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.010] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_ffmpeg470_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.011] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_ffmpeg470_64.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.011] global backend_plugin.cpp:383 cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER

[ INFO:0@0.011] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\opencv_videoio_gstreamer470_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.011] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_gstreamer470_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.012] global backend_plugin.cpp:383 cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for INTEL_MFX

[ INFO:0@0.012] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\opencv_videoio_intel_mfx470_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.012] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_intel_mfx470_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0@0.155] global cap_msmf.cpp:1027 CvCapture_MSMF::configureHW MSMF: Using D3D11 video acceleration on GPU device: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080

[ INFO:0@0.331] global cap_images.cpp:282 cv::icvExtractPattern Pattern: rtsp://admin:L2CF4E9B@192.168.0.15:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=%01d&subtype=0 @ 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 29 seconds)

**El código que utilizo es el siguiente:**

```
public class EnVivo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private JLabel imageLabel;
private VideoCapture capture;

public EnVivo() {
    super("Camera Capture");
    initComponents();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 600);

    imageLabel = new JLabel();
    add(imageLabel);

    setVisible(true);

    startCapture();

}

private void startCapture() {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    capture = new VideoCapture();
    capture.open("rtsp://admin:pass@ip:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0");
    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            Mat frame = new Mat();

            while (true) {
                if (capture.read(frame)) {
                    BufferedImage image = convertMatToBufferedImage(frame);
                    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                    pack();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } else {
        System.err.println("Failed to open the camera.");
    }
}
private BufferedImage convertMatToBufferedImage(Mat frame) {
    int width = frame.width();
    int height = frame.height();
    int channels = frame.channels();
    byte[] data = new byte[width * height * channels];

    frame.get(0, 0, data);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, targetPixels, 0, data.length);

    return image;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;

            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EnVivo.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EnVivo.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EnVivo.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EnVivo.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new EnVivo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

}